# Problema al mostrar modelo en Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Hola como estan? Hice los modelos desde una BD existente, pero no logro mostrar los mismos en el panel admin. Cual puede ser el problema?
Dede ya muchas gracias

Model:

```html
class Muestra(models.Model):
    departamento_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    numero = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tipo_prestacion = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    entrada = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    nro_cert_cadena_custodia = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    matriz_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tipomuestra_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    muestra = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'muestra'
```

Admin:

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Muestra)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene pinta de que no has registrado el nombre de la App, por lo que no aparece en el Admin.

En el archivo settings.py ¿Has agregado tu aplicación en "INSTALLED_APPS"? Doy por hecho que sí. Si no, el problema es ése. Y además, en ese caso, tendrás que hacer el makemigrations y el migrate antes de poder entrar al admin panel.

En el archivo urls.py (el que esté en la misma carpeta que el models.py), arriba del todo añade el app_name:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
....
app_name = '<el nombre de tu aplicación>'

urlpatterns = [....]
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, repase de nuevo las migraciones y anduvo!